# escape_Q in my perl doesn't recognize the brackets

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

I have two lines in a file, both ends with testInst_Wdata_w0_reg/Jreg_ff[0].SSS.nr

```
A...testInst_Wdata_w0_reg/Jreg_ff[0].SSS.nr, 

B...testInst_Wdata_w0_reg/Jreg_ff[0].SSS.nr
```

I want to compare the common part. But there is "[]", it seems can't match.

I checked other threads, people suggest using \Q as the [] has special meaning in pattern

```
($ref =~ m/\Q$matching_ref_end$/))
```

$matching_ref_end == testInst_Wdata_w0_reg/Jreg_ff[0].SSS.nr

So i have the above, but it seems not working.

Any hints?

Comment: Read [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) and see what you are missing in your code.

Comment: Is in `m/\Q$matching_ref_end$/` dollar sign at the end intentional? It will not match first line as it ends with `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the lines truly do end with the contents `$matching_ref_end` as you claim,

```
/\Q$matching_ref_end$/
```

should be

```
/\Q$matching_ref_end\E$/
```

because the `\Q` is escaping the `$`.

(Actually, it should be `/\Q$matching_ref_end\E\z/` unless you want to accept trailing line feed.)

One of the lines you showed doesn't actually end with the contents `$matching_ref_end` as you claim, however. One has a trailing comma you'll need to handle.